# when I use ButterKnife 8.4.0 error: a exception:Error:Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.0

Tags: android

When I user **ButterKnife** 8.4.0 an error occurs:

> exception:Error:Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.01.

The IDE is Android Studio 2.2, added the apt.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }

} dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
  compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
  apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: show your `build.gradle`

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
}

Comment: `buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"`

Comment: As @IntelliJAmiya says, you need to change your build tools version to 24.0.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the version of compile SDK, build tool version, target SDK version, and support library. If you make your app support API 24, you need to change all the value to API 24. Like this:

```
...

android {
  compileSdkVersion 24 // Using API 24
  buildToolsVersion "24.0.2" // Using API 24

  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 24 // Using API 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
  }

} dependencies {
  ...
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0' // Using the latest API support 24
  ...
}
```

Comment: add `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'`

Answer (score 0):

Remove all butterknife dependencies and add:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

Comment: But i want use the latest

Comment: In that case you should upgrade your build version to latest 24+

Comment: You mean the buildToolsVersion?

Comment: Yes, you need to upgrade your Android SDK to latest